# Instead of pendingIntent, execute function in Notification.addAction() . Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I want a method to be executed when I press a button on my notification. For that purpose I am adding an action with a `PendingIntent` to my notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                    .setContentText("Click Here")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Test2", pendingIntent)
                    .build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(0, notification);
```

That works, however I don't want to start an `Activity` when the user invokes the action. I just need to do some work.

For that purpose I implemented a `Service` which should be targeted by the `PendingIntent` instead:

```
public class MyServices extends IntentService {
    public MyServices() {
        super("MyServices");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        clearNotification();
    }

    public void clearNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyServices.this, MainActivity.class); 
//Starting new activity just to check
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I create the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyServices.class);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

However when I invoke the action on my notification nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No that's no possible. What's wrong with `PendingIntent`? Just use that.

Comment: You do know that you can start other components - not just Activities - with a `PendingIntent`,  right? Just use a `Service`.

Comment: I want some code to be executed without actually starting any activity (or showing anything to the user).

Like, suppose the notification says; "Is it raining?"
Action button 1: Yes 
Action button 2: No.

When clicked yes, lead the user to some activity.
**When clicked No, clear notification and execute a small piece of code**

Comment: So don't start an Activity. What's the problem? Just start a `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` instead.

Comment: Also that would be a really weird use case for a notification,  I don't recommend you include any notifications like that in your app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Notification is not part of your application. It is managed by the OS. It just so happens that there are APIs you can use to show/cancel/etc notifications.

A pending intent allows for external code (Notifications for example) to launch your app/activity/service/broadcastreceiver. This cannot be done without a pending intent.

> What my task is to execute some piece of code when a specific action button is clicked, and clear notification; without starting any activity

You don't have to start an activity. You can do it in a  broadcastreceiver that has no UI. Or, as CommonsWare suggested, use an IntentService, depending on what what you are doing in your "piece of code". IntentServices handle work in a separate thread.

Comment: Even better: do it in an `IntentService`, if the work to be done will take more than a millisecond or so.

Comment: But nothing is happening when I click "No" button

Comment: @AseedUsmani Edit your question, don't post code in the comments. For now I have already taken care of editing your question for you.

Comment: @AseedUsmani And define "nothing happens". Have you debugged your `Service`? Is it really not called? Is there no entry in the log which explains what is happening?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Nothing comes in logcat, and I get "No" button, but when I click it nothing happens whatsoever. I'm trying to clear the notification when "No" is clicked, and then start MainActivity (just to test) but that doesn't happen either!

How shall I debug?

Comment: Have you named your `Service` really just `Service`? Give it another name. I think you are importing the framework `Service` class instead if your `Service` class when creating the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I renamed it to notiServices, yet nothing happens (no log entries either but that may be because notification is not a component of the app)

Comment: @TimCastelijns The question is still the same, how to remove notification without actually showing the app to the user by clicking no button. Intent Service, as suggested in your answer isn't working.

Comment: @XaverKapeller what should I put as context parameter? I think the mistake is that I am passing Activity.this as context but Notification is not a part of the Application but UI?

Comment: Ya you should just past `context`

Comment: `context` gives an error `cannot resolve symbol`. context needs to be initialized somewhere right?

Comment: but you use it here as well `Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);`

Comment: That `context` is actualy `Activity.this`. 
But using that "No" button which I am adding is not working.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference which context you use. And you are sure that there is nothing in your log? Have you debugged your service yet? Are you sure it really isn't called?

Comment: Also you cannot start an `Activity` like that in your `Service`. When starting an `Activity` from a `Service` you need to set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag on your `Intent`.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am getting nothing in logs, starting an activity is a secondary task; primary task is to clear notification with `id=0`.

For which I wrote: 
`NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

        `notificationManager.cancel(0);`

Comment: On a side note: Activities do not necessarily need to display something to the user. You can fire up an activity from the pending intent, do all the work in onCreate without setting a layout, and finally call finish on the activity when done.  Add "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"  to the style of the activity and the user will not note anything.

Comment: @GPuschka true, but why would you use an activity then, doesn't make much sense

Comment: Have any of you ever done this? If yes, share the code? - Clearing notification when clicked on an action button (notification.addAction() ) without opening any activity (user sees nothing) . Like it happens in gmail app.

Comment: @TimCastelijns well, it does some task and is quite lightweight so one can use it as well. But yeah, in the end its a design decision.